# WebRTC video: false on one user turns video off for both

Tags: webrtc

I am having a strange issue with WebRTC.

Two peers are connected through RTCPeerConnection.

One with getusermedia {video: false, audio: true}

and the other getusermedia {video: true, audio: true}

The problem is that video is turned off for both!

Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

I am using adapter.js from https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS/blob/master/source/adapter.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call createOffer with {offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1}, especially if the user that does not request video is creating the connection.